# How to know which uninstaller has been invoked if multiple uninstallers are present

Tags: nsis

I have a requirement to create two uninstallers with different names. Each will remove different folders. I am using the same project/script to create uninstallers. How can i find that which uninstaller has been invoked by the user? So that i can use that value in un.onInit and remove the corresponding folders?

Similarly if the same script is creating two installers, how to find which installer has been invoked by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Installers:**

```
Section
!ifdef INSTALLER_OTHER
DetailPrint "Other"
!else
DetailPrint "Normal"
!endif
SectionEnd
```

Generate the other installer with `makensis.exe /DINSTALLER_OTHER setup.nsi`

**Uninstallers:**

You could check the uninstaller filename:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section un.Whatever
${GetExeName} $0
${GetBaseName} $0 $0 ; Remove path and extension
${If} $0 == "OtherUninst"
    RMDir "Other"
${Else}
    RMDir "Normal"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Or the installer can write a special file that you check for.

Or embed special data in the uninstaller:

```
InstallDir "$Temp\TestInst"
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
FileOpen $0 "$InstDir\Uninst.exe" a
FileSeek $0 0 END
!ifdef INSTALLER_OTHER
FileWriteByte $0 1
!else
FileWriteByte $0 0
!endif
FileClose $0
SectionEnd

Section -Uninstall
FileOpen $0 "$EXEPATH" r
FileSeek $0 -1 END
FileReadByte $0 $1
FileClose $0
${If} $1 = 1
    RMDir "Other"
${Else}
    RMDir "Normal"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of Anders solutions, you could go for a registry write-read method. It will be a quick operation i.e. Whenever you run any uninstaller just write a registry value and set it's value. Afterwards you just need to read that registry values and process accordingly.